# Filter a SharePoint-List as you type with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: 2010, list, javascript, search-results

so my scenario is: My users don't like the filter technology provided in SP2010 Lists and Listviews (using the row-titles' dropdown) and likes to have a "normal" textbox and search the splist (one column, perhaps more) with this textbox, like known from google or... lets say the whole other web ;).

So what I've done yet is adding a Form Web Part to the lists(views) page and connected it to the list view. It works, though, but I don't like the behaviour that (having a listitem with title="Testitem") typing only *text* and klicking on start/go-button, the entry *testitem* don't show up. It only shows up, giving in *Testitem* as whole.

So i thought about a "search as you type" / "autocomplete"-feature based on javascript, but to be honest I don't know how to do this and hope for some suggestions. I did a search here and on google, and just found something like this for SP2007 (perhaps my searchskills are not that good? d'oh), but nothing for SP2010. Would be nice to get a tutorial/third party javascript (with readable sources).

Best regards,
Dominik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily using a combination of Jquery SharePoint 2010 REST Services. Following are some of the useful links:

1. [SharePoint 2010 autocomplete textbox containing listitems](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3A%2F%2Ftomvangaever.be%2Fblogv2%2F2011%2F07%2Fsharepoint-2010-autocomplete-with-list-items%2F&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&oq=cache%3A%2F%2Ftomvangaever.be%2Fblogv2%2F2011%2F07%2Fsharepoint-2010-autocomplete-with-list-items%2F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j69i60.5742j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).
2. [Building a jQuery Autocomplete textbox using the SharePoint REST API](http://sharepointdragons.com/2011/12/09/building-a-jquery-autocomplete-textbox-using-the-sharepoint-rest-api/).

Remember that `ListData.svc` uses the title of the list minus spaces:

[SharePoint 2010 REST API](http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2012/01/sharepoint-2010-rest-api.html)