# Autocomplete Text Filter Webpart

Tags: filter

So I have to setup a text filter that is connected to a big list of names. Is it possible to configure some kind of autocomplete on this text filter to help users?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several ways of doing it. One of them is using JQuery and SharePoint REST API. See my answer to a similar question here:
[Filter a SharePoint-List as you type with Javascript/jQuery](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58116/filter-a-sharepoint-list-as-you-type-with-javascript-jquery)